# local software using web technologies

Tags: web-applications, gwt

Is it possible to write a local software (read/write local files) using web technologies such as google web toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can create an [hta "html application"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx) that gives JavaScript elevated privileges. This only runs on IE.

You can deploy an [embedded web server](http://appwebserver.org/) with all your code on it if you need server side processing. this would be typically done with an installer. The client could be a IE com object in a windows form app. This gives you all the power of IE (lol) in an executable

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), a webapp you drop into a web container (tomcat, jetty, ...), and it will read/write files on that machine.